# Change <div> to <a> and add attributes/class using Jquery

Tags: jquery, attr, replacewith

I have an example of something I trying to achieve but not having success.

jQuery:

```
$('#change').click(function() {
var $planHeaders = $('.plan > div > div:first-child');
$planHeaders.replaceWith($('<a>' + 'homeboy' + '</a>')).attr("href",     "javascript:void(0);").addClass('tile');
$('.plan > div > div:last-child').hide();
});
```

Example on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95YCr/1/

Basically what I want to do is once this gets to mobile/tablet size is change the header  to an  tag and remove the button within the .plan div.

This example isn't responsive, I'm just using this as a test version with the #change link working as my "responsive view activation".

I'm noticing the neither the href attribute or class are being added to the desired tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `replaceWith` returns the replaced element, not the new element.

Comment: Just a tip, you should avoid things like `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('open');` use `.closest()` or `.parents()` when possible.

Comment: You're adding the attributes to `$planHeaders`, not the new `<a>` tag. the attr/addclass calls should be INSIDE the `replaceWith()` call, most likely.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
.attr("href", "javascript:void(0);").addClass('tile')
```

to execute against

```
$('<a>' + 'homeboy' + '</a>')
```

Such that the line becomes

```
$planHeaders.replaceWith($('<a>' + 'homeboy' + '</a>').attr("href", "javascript:void(0);").addClass('tile'));
```

The reason is you are adding the attributes and classes to an element you have just replaced, not the one you replaced it with.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95YCr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to create the link its a neater syntax in jquery and should solve your problems

```
$('<a>', { className: 'title', href: 'javascript:void(0);'} ).append('homeboy');
```

An example is here http://jsfiddle.net/domjgreen/K65w4/

Answer (score 0):

In your case you a referring to the element `$planHeaders` not to the new anchor that you are creating.

The replaceWith method:

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided
>   new content and return the set of elements that was removed.

so add the attribute to the anchor element inside the `replaceWith` method call.

Code:

```
$planHeaders.replaceWith($('<a>homeboy</a>').attr("href", "javascript:void(0);").addClass('tile'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ss7F4/